# Time comparison for data load using pyspark vs pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I am new to spark. I assume that when you read data(in my case csv) using spark, it by defaults create multiple tasks and read the file in parallel chunks. I am reading a same file using SqlContext and pandas, apparently the read using spark is taking longer than pandas. Would anyone know if there is a any difference between how the file is read between, and why using SqlContext is taking longer ?

```
df = pd.read_csv('loan.csv')
```

and

```
rdd = sqlContext.read.load ('loan.csv',
                            format='com.databricks.spark.csv',
                            header='true',
                            inferSchema='true')
```

I used pyspark to initiate the context with default configurations. File is around 1.5 GB. I am using my local machine , using following code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext('local',"test app")
sqlContext = SQLContext (sc)
```

Comment: How did you start the spark shell? What was the command that you used ? Also, it would be good for you to provide details on how big the file size is and how does your cluster setup look like and where is loan.csv file in the cluster. The more information yo provide the easier it is to get help from the community.

Comment: wow, wasn't expecting a community response here this soon. Thanks for responding. I am new to this platform and still learning. I used pyspark to initiate the context with default configurations. File is around 1.5 GB. I am using my local machine , using following code:

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext('local',"test app")
sqlContext = SQLContext (sc)

Comment: Can you update your question with the details ? With the current details it is very hard to suggest why one is slower than the other.

Comment: How did you test the end to end latency for the two processes?

Comment: using execute time extention from nbExtension widget in jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a spark application in `local` mode it basically means that the Driver and Executor are running in the same JVM and it uses the number of threads that you specify.

In this specific case only `local` has been mentioned and the below table shows what are the different different parameters that can be passed in local mode and its impact. More details can be found in the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls)

```
Master URL  Meaning
local       Run Spark locally with one worker thread (i.e. no parallelism at all).
local[K]    Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine).
local[K,F]  Run Spark locally with K worker threads and F maxFailures (see spark.task.maxFailures for an explanation of this variable)
```

Having said that when you try to compare a Spark application with Pandas processing capabilities there can be multiple situations where Pandas will outshine Spark when Spark runs on a single thread as Spark is not meant to run on a single thread.

Spark shines when you run a Spark application on multiple machines and each machine running multiple tasks. As both of these are complementary tools that is the reason pandas is now integrated into Spark so that developers can get the best of both worlds. More details can be found [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Jayadeep, this is helpful. i didn't know that the default option (local) will just run spark with single worker thread. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: If this answered your question, do accept the answer.

Comment: i think it does answer my question, how do i accept an answer. Trying to figure out if there is a button for that. ?

Comment: did it. Is there a way to follow a user on stack overflow ?  or tag you or specific user in a future question possibly ? Also, i have 5 cores on my system, but it is even letting me do sc = SparkContext('local[10]',"test app"). Am i doing something wrong in the syntax ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to follow an user in SO. Also, if you ask questions in SO there are many people active who answer to questions.